# latexmk with external references

Tags: latexmk

Is there a way to make latexmk aware of external references as they are imported via the xr package? My Problem is that I have several files for weekly exercise sheets. Sometimes I have references to earlier exercises which I include via the xr package (neat thing...). As mistakes happen, I  sometimes have to correct an exercise sheet after the next one has been issued. So I want a `latexmk file2` recognize that `file1` has changed and hence `file1` has to be recompiled again before working on `file2`...?

Of course, I can (and actually do) put everything in a big make file which calls the latexmk commands on the individual files according to their dependencies but is there a latexmk-intrinsic way to automate this?

Answer (score 16):

- The following **marks the dependencies** on the external `tex` and `aux` files in the main file, even if those files do not already exist (there is otherwise no `tex` file dependency and the `aux` file dependency doesn't automatically happen if the file doesn't exist - the warning generated by the `xr` package is not processed by `latexmk` because it is different to the standard LaTeX warnings; namely it is missing a period after the filename).
- It then uses a **custom dependency** to `latexmk` such that it knows how to build `aux` files. If an `aux` file with a different root filename needs to be regenerated, it causes `latexmk` to process the corresponding job (in a **separate system call**). Note that with this approach, any warnings from `latexmk` generated while processing the external documents will **not** be summarised at the end of the main run, and the concepts of `$max_repeat` and `Run number $pass{$rule} of rule '$rule'` are weakened!
- This works best when `latexmk` has the `recorder` option activated (default since v4.31, otherwise enabled through the command line option `-recorder=1` or appropriate line in `.latexmkrc`); without this, changes to the external `aux` files may be missed, though changes to the external `tex` files will still start the correct processing.
- Currently, this requires use of the command **`\myexternaldocument`** instead of `\externaldocument`, though the original command could be patched.

I have provided the code in the context of a minimum example (though none was provided in the question) for better illustratation. Three files are shown below: `file1.tex`, `file2.tex` and `.latexmkrc`.

- `file1` references something in `file2`.
- Executing `latexmk file1` is sufficient to correctly build both `file1` and `file2`.
- Remember that using the `-deps` option to `latexmk` will show the dependency database and may help to verify how things are working.
- Note the commented line in `file2.tex` to facilitate testing.

Here's `file1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% HELPER CODE FOR DEALING WITH EXTERNAL REFERENCES
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
  \typeout{(#1)}% latexmk will find this if $recorder=0 (however, in that case, it will ignore #1 if it is a .aux or .pdf file etc and it exists! if it doesn't exist, it will appear in the list of dependents regardless)
  \@addtofilelist{#1}% if you want it to appear in \listfiles, not really necessary and latexmk doesn't use this
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}% latexmk will find this message if #1 doesn't exist (yet)
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
    \externaldocument{#1}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}
%%% END HELPER CODE

% put all the external documents here!
\myexternaldocument{file2}

% just to see what's happening
\listfiles

\begin{document}

Label1 is on page \pageref{label1} of file2.

\end{document}
```

And `file2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
%\lipsum[1-10]% to test, comment or uncomment this line, and rerun `latexmk file1`. Note that both are then rebuilt as necessary and the page number in the generated `file1` is always correct.
\section{Label1}
\label{label1}
This is referenced by file1.
\end{document}
```

And finally `.latexmkrc`:

```
add_cus_dep( 'tex', 'aux', 0, 'makeexternaldocument' );

sub makeexternaldocument {
    # if the dependency isn't one of the files that this latexmk run will consider, process it
    # without this test, we would get an infinite loop!
    if (!($root_filename eq $_[0]))
    {
        system( "latexmk \"$_[0]\"" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Really helpful answer cyberSingularity.  Many thanks.  I have modified the definition of \myexternaldocument to allow the optional tag for the external document reference, and it seems to work well: `\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[2][]{%
    \externaldocument[#1]{#2}%
    \addFileDependency{#2.tex}%
    \addFileDependency{#2.aux}%
}

\myexternaldocument[mapp:]{MovantsAppendix}
`

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed answer! Sadly, it seems to result in warnings with current `latexmk` versions, namely: `
``Latexmk: Possible bug:
  In linking rules, I already set from_rules_main{file1.aux}
  to 'cusdep tex aux file1'
  But now I also have a different rule 'latex' that also made the file.```
This is also mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600689/224985).

Comment: Does this work with cyclic references (`file1` references `file2`, and `file2` references `file1`)? I'm getting an apparently infinite loop. Manually running `pdflatex` on both files a couple of times works fine though.

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful! It has actually been adapted to an [Overleaf guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf#When_should_I_use_the_xr_package.3F), for anyone that wants to easily play around with it. 

I also modified the `\myexternaldocument` command to add tags, and defined a `\newcommand{\myexternalref}[1]{\ref{mytag:#1}}` for each of the externals to simplify referencing with tags.

Comment: Is there a way to add a prefix to the original labels? For example, I would like Theorem 2.2 from file1.tex to be cited as Theorem I.2.2 in file2.tex. The xr package admits options to \externaldocument: \externaldocument[I.]{file1}. Can this be adapted to overleaf?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an internal link between the two or multiple files I doubt latexmk would recognize this. So the 2 cases are:

1. Internal link between multiple files: For example if file1.tex had this phrase, latexmk will recognize the need to recompile if there are changes in file2 or file3 etc

   %file1.tex

   ```
   \begin{document}

   \input{file2.tex}
   \input{file3.tex}

   \end{document}
   ```

   %end of file1.tex
2. Make file: But then if you use a for loop in a make file or a normal unix script file which says something like this:

   ```
   for /r %%x in (*.tex) do pdflatex "%%x"
   ```

   then there is a meagre change LaTeX would recognize it but then its just a for loop instead of individual lines of latexmk execution.

I hope this was of some help. Looking forward to see if anyone else had a solution for you.