# Cross references and subfiles

Tags: cross-referencing, subfiles, xr

I want to take references between subfiles for a big project, the main 
structure is for the main files is `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{xr} 
\externaldocument[I-]{intro/intro}                                                                                             
\externaldocument[A-]{ante/ante}

 \begin{document}
  \chapter{chap1}
    \subfile{intro/intro.tex}
   \chapter{chap2}
    \subfile{ante/ante.tex}     
  \end{document}
```

and subfile 1 intro.tex:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
  ... \section{secA}\label{sec:secta}
 \end{document}
```

and subfile 2 ante.tex:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
  ... in \ref{I-sec:secta}
 \end{document}
```

but the thing is that I just receive "**... in (??)**" instead the number of the reference "**in (number)**" in the output file `ante.pdf`, I' ve tried change the paths but I still have the `??` in the reference number. Does anyone have a idea how to fix this?, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Sharelatex ? -- How are you compiling your project ? -- Have you seen the error messages in the log ? -- note that `\externaldocument[I-]{intro}`  requires the `.aux` files. If you do not have the `.aux` files in the corresponding directories, you will get an error.

Comment: Hi @Jaime, Thanks for the answer, I am using pdflatex to compile the project, I have a .aux file in each directory, now I was able to obtain a number inside the parenthesis "..in ( )" but the number is wrong, for example I have "(0.1.2)" but the correct section reference is "(1.1.2)"

Comment: Do you have a minimal example we can check?

Comment: when cross refererencing in overleaf i found this useful http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69832/226

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compilation of `ante.tex` will not resolve the cross reference for `intro.tex` since it has not any information that there is `intro.tex` at all.

Use `\externaldocument[I-]{../intro/intro}` in `ante.tex` again.

```
\documentclass[../subfilesmain.tex]{subfiles}
\externaldocument[I-]{../intro/intro} 
\begin{document}
in \ref{I-sec:secta}
\end{document}
```

`subfilesmain.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{xr} 
\externaldocument[I-]{intro/intro}                                                                                             
\externaldocument[A-]{ante/ante}

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{chap1}
 \subfile{intro/intro.tex}
 \chapter{chap2}
 \subfile{ante/ante.tex}     
\end{document}
```

`intro.tex`

```
\documentclass[../subfilesmain.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
... \section{secA}\label{sec:secta}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, with your answer I was able to obtain the number of the references in each individual file and in the "Main" file as well, but I still have the problem with the wrong numbers related with the numeration of the chapters, for example I have something as **" ... in (0.3.2)"** but I need **"... in (2.3.2)"**, now I have to figure out how to fix this

Comment: @mors: The result is `0.1` because the `intro` file does not have any chapter and so the chapter number is `0`. If you want to include the chapter number, the `\chapter` command should go the `intro` file etc. as well

Comment: In order to re-fetch references, should I compile all subfiles one-by-one as well before the main file?