# Cross referecing two documents to each other

Tags: cross-referencing, latexmk, overleaf

I have two files which I want to cross-reference to each other. following this [latexmk with external references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/latexmk-with-external-references/69832#69832) this is what I did. I am compiling in overleaf.

In file 1 I have the following:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{
    \externaldocument{#1}
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}
}

\myexternaldocument{D_appendix}
```

In file 2 this is what I have

```
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{
    \externaldocument{#1}
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}
}

\myexternaldocument{A_main}
```

Any idea what I have to do with the latexmkrc file? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ The procedure may fail if your `A_main.tex` contains some compile errors, or due to the version of `xr.sty` your project is using. It may be easier to debug if you contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, thanks!