# Unable to reference figure from one subfile to another subfile when compiling ONLY the subfile

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf, subfiles, xr

I have the following files in Overleaf:

`main.tex` in root directory:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\section{Methodology} \label{methodology}
\subfile{section/methodology}

\section{Results and Discussion} \label{discussion}
\subfile{section/discussion}

\end{document}
```

and 2 subfiles in directory `section`:

`discussion.tex`, which as a figure with label `fig:myfig`:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{myfig.pdf}
\caption{My Figure.}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Then, in my other subfile `methodology.tex`, I want to refer to `fig:myfig`:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\externaldocument{discussion}

\begin{document}

I want to refer to Figure \ref{fig:myfig}

\end{document}
```

If I compile `main.tex`, the figure is referenced just fine. But if I only compile `methodology.tex`, I got `??` in Figure reference. How do I reference this correctly?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf

Comment: that shows how to reference between 2 independent files. In my case, 2 files are subfiles and linked to a `main.tex` outside

Comment: The method works for your example; see https://www.overleaf.com/read/bckpkfcfxntb As long as you want to use `xr` you need the extra helper code and `latexmkrc` to get the `.aux` for `methodology.tex` when you're compiling (latexmk) from `discussion.tex` as a subfile. The technique actually comes from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/latexmk-with-external-references/69832#69832

Comment: You have to run `LaTeX` first on `discussion.tex` and then on `methodology.tex`. On my local installation (not Overleaf) your code works fine (except that one has to add `\usepackage{graphicx}` in `main` and replace `myfig.pdf` by `example-image`.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that on my local PC, I use `latexmk` to build `discussion` first and then `methodology` but still, it gives `??`. Could you paste your working code and command to build (in order) as the answer?

Comment: Done. Note that you have to add `@gernotsaysReinstateMonica` to your comment in order to notify me about your answer. Otherwise I will notice it only if I come back by chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a local TeX installation, the code of the example in the question (almost) works. The required changes have nothing to do with the packages `xr` and `subfiles`, but just make the loading of the image work.
So if there are problems on Overleaf, they are caused by the specific setting there, not by the packages.

The file structure is as follows:

```
main.tex
section/discussion.tex
section/methodology.tex
```

Typesetting `main.tex` and `section/discussion.tex` works as usual: run `latex` twice.

To typeset `section/methodology.tex`, you have first to run `latex` once on `discussion.tex` (this produces `discussion.aux`, which holds the labels from `discussion.tex`), and then once on `methodology.tex` (this run reads `discussion.aux`):

```
cd section
pdflatex discussion
pdflatex methodology
```

Here is the contents of the three files.

```
% main.tex
\listfiles % to get the list of loaded packages with version information
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Methodology} \label{methodology}
\subfile{section/methodology}
\section{Results and Discussion} \label{discussion}
\subfile{section/discussion}
\end{document}

% section/discussion.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{My Figure.}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

% section/methodology.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\externaldocument{discussion}
\begin{document}
I want to refer to Figure \ref{fig:myfig}
\end{document}
```

For reference, here is the list of loaded packages with information on the versions used. You obtain it by adding `\listfiles` as first line in `main.tex`. The list appears at the end of the log output.

```
 *File List*
IEEEtran.cls    2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2019/11/01 v1.3d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
      xr.sty    2019/07/22 v5.05 eXternal References (DPC)
subfiles.sty    2019/10/30 v1.5 Multi-file projects (package)
  import.sty    2009/03/23  v 5.1
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2019/11/04 v1.0b TeX engine tests
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
methodology.tex
discussion.tex
example-image.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ***********
```