# Unable to reference chapter from main to subfile when compiling ONLY the subfile

Tags: cross-referencing

I have the following code in my main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xr} 
\usepackage{subfiles} % Best loaded last in the preamble
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sobolev}
\subfile{sobolev}

\chapter{functional} \label{appendix:functional}
\end{document}
```

and the following in my subfile which is sobolev.tex

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\externaldocument{main.tex}

\begin{document}

The functional analysis terminology may be 
referred to in Appendix \ref{appendix:functional}.

\end{document}
```

When compiling the subfile, the reference doesn't show up.

A similar question was asked here ([Unable to reference figure from one subfile to another subfile when compiling ONLY the subfile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516153/unable-to-reference-figure-from-one-subfile-to-another-subfile-when-compiling-on)).
I've tried compiling main followed by compiling sobolev, it still shows the same error.

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me (the reference shows up). Try updating your LaTeX distribution and running your MWE again (first compiling `main.tex`, then `sobolev.tex`).

Comment: As a side note, the documentation states that `\externaldocument` should go into `main.tex`, not into `sobolev.tex`, but both versions work for me.

Comment: `main.tex` is compiled without issues. It doesn't find cross reference if I compile `sobolev.tex`. I believe it means it doesn't really work.

Comment: I can confirm it's working now but only if I run both files from command line. Normally, I use Atom with a plugin. I also put all auxiliary and output files in the custom folder: `out/`. If I run the following line: `latexmk -pdflua -auxdir=out/ -outdir=out/ sobolev.tex`, assuming I compiled the `main.tex` before, I get the correct referencing. So in my case, it was a problem with the configuration and the fact LaTeX couldn't find required files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\externaldocument{main.tex}` by `\externaldocument{main}`, then it works.

Actually, when running LaTeX on `sobolev.tex`, the log file contains the complaint:

```
Package xr Warning: 
No file main.tex.aux
LABELS NOT IMPORTED.
 on input line 2.
```

Apparently, the `xr` package just appends `.aux` to the string provided by `\externaldocument` and takes this as the filename with the label information.

Comment: Sorry, I commented in a wrong place.

Comment: When I use main instead of main.tex, sobolev.aux file shows an error saying labels of references are multiply defined. I'm using bibtex.

Comment: @Abhinav This has nothing to do with `subfiles` but how you use the `xr` package. In the preamble of your main file, add the lines `\usepackage{xr}\usepackage{subfiles}\externaldocument[M-]{\subfix{main}}`, and remove `\usepackage{xr}` and `\externaldocument` from your subfiles. If you define a label `xxx` somewhere (via `\label{xxx}`), then `\ref{M-xxx}` will give you the value like when compiling the main document. See the [documentation of the subfiles package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf), section 4.2

Comment: The `multiply defined` errors are the result of loading `main.aux` (via `\externaldocument`) as well as `sub.aux`. Any label defined in `sub.tex` will appear in both `aux` files (hence it seems multiply defined). The optional `M-` parameter tells LaTeX to prefix the labels loaded from `main.aux` with `M-` such that you (and LaTeX) can distinguish the value the label has in the main document (`\ref{M-xxx}) and in the subfile (`\ref{xxx}`).

Comment: Thanks! that resolved the issue!