# Compile appendix but don't print it

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, cross-referencing, appendix

I have a report that is 50 pages with a 250 page appendix. I want to create two PDF files, one with and without the appendix. The main chapters of the report reference the appendices, and so I want those links to be preserved.

I'm compiling the report with pdfLaTeX (and Knitr). I tried using the R package `pdftools` but that breaks my hyperlinks.

Is there a LaTeX based solution to this? I've seen people use pdftk, but I don't have access to this on my computer at work.

Here's an example. I want to compile the entire report to keep the links and references, but don't want the appendix included.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Report}
    Report body.

    I want to reference \ref{sec:appendix1}

    \appendix

    \chapter{Appendix}
    Here's a really long appendix with a reference \label{sec:appendix1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be looking for `\include` and `\includeonly`.

Comment: I am using those, but when you don’t include the appendix, it doesn’t create the references (they show up as ??) unless I’m mistaken

Comment: You need to compile it once with `\includeonly{main,appendix}`, where `main.tex` contains `\chapter{Report}
    Report body.

    I want to reference \ref{sec:appendix1}` and `appendix.tex` contains `\appendix

    \chapter{Appendix}
    Here's a really long appendix with a reference \label{sec:appendix1}.`. After the first compilation you can use `\includeonly{main}` and the references will show (since you have created the aux file in the first run) but the appendix will no longer be compiled nor shown in the resulting pdf.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Simple solution.

Comment: Hi, how to do it on Overleaf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [latexmk with external references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/latexmk-with-external-references)

Comment: @Mensch -- The poster who provided the useful answer is no longer active, but the answer is nice and "clean", and I can't find a decent duplicate.  Can you post an answer including this information?  It would be too bad to lose it, which could happen if this question is deleted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I retracted my close vote and added an answer ...

Comment: @Mensch -- Nice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in an comment user `user194703` mentioned, that commands `\include` and `\includeonly` can do what you want. Let us take a look into details ...

Please see that you need two tex files, for example `main.tex`

```
\chapter{Report}
Report body.

I want to reference \ref{sec:appendix1}
```

and `appendix.tex`

```
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
Here's a really long appendix with a reference \label{sec:appendix1}.
```

to be included in your file `mwe.tex` like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\includeonly{main,appendix}% <========================================== first compile run
%\includeonly{main}% <================================================== second and more runs

\begin{document}

\include{main.tex} % <==================================================

\include{appendix.tex}% <===============================================

\end{document}
```

Command `\includeonly{main,appendix}` in your preamble includes **only** the two files `main.tex` and `appendix.tex` (there might be more files included in your document) into the compile run with the result that you get the two files `main.aux` and `appendix.aux` containing the needed informations for correct references.

Please see that after the first run you see only `??` instead a reference (that is okay! a second run is needed).

For the second (and third etc) run move the `%`sign to have only command `\includeonly{main}` called:

```
\documentclass{report}

%\includeonly{main,appendix}
\includeonly{main}% <================================================== second and more runs

\begin{document}

\include{main.tex} % <==================================================

\include{appendix.tex}% <===============================================

\end{document}
```

Then you get thw wished result: no appendix printed, but the reference to Appendix A is printed as you can see in the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Great answer, nonetheless more care is needed for the bibliography, otherwise citations from the appendix will bleed into the bibliography. If one wants the short version: bibtex/biber should be run while the appendix is not included and there is no file appendix.aux.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple tutorial for you:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf

It solved my problem.