# Can Overleaf accommodate pre-fixes for xr-hyper (e.g, \myexternaldocument[ext1-]{path...})

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, overleaf, xr

**Short version**: when using `xr` or `xr-hyper` on Overleaf, is it possible to add prefixes to external documents to avoid multiple defined labels (as defined [here](https://texblog.org/2016/08/23/adding-references-from-an-external-file/))?

**Longer version**: I'm drafting a review memo on Overleaf which refers to a Manuscript and Appendix that are also on Overleaf. The review memo refers to corrected/new figures and tables in both of the other documents, so I've used `xr-hyper` to refer to them. Unsurprisingly, since I've replicated some of those figures in the review memo and labeled them, I'm running into the problem of "multiply defined labels." Normally I'd just remove the labels in the captions of the figures replicated in the review memo, but ideally, I'd like to have something like the following in the review memo:

> We respond to this comment by adding Figure XXX below, which appears as Figure YYY in the manuscript"

Whenever I try to change the references to the external files in the review memo from `\myexternaldocument{Manuscript}` to `\myexternaldocument[ext-1]{Manuscript}` --- as suggested [here](https://texblog.org/2016/08/23/adding-references-from-an-external-file/) --- Overleaf throws the error `label ... multiply defined.` The same thing happens when I use `\externaldocument{...}`. Rather than relabeling all the replicated figures in the review memo, is it possible to modify the latexmkrc script ([required](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf) to use xr and xr-hyper with Overleaf) to accommodate the use of prefixes?

Comment: Is your definition of `\myexternaldocument` similar to the one in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69832? If so, you'll have to modify it so that it accepts an optional argument to be passed to `\externaldocument`

Comment: Yes it’s a modification of /externaldocument that Overleaf requires to make “xr” work: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments you mentioned that you're using the definitions from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69832, which has:

```
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
    \externaldocument{#1}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}
```

But this definition accepts only one argument: there's no way to pass another optional argument along to `\externaldocument`. Therefore you'll have to adapt the definition to

```
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[2][]{%
    \externaldocument[#1]{#2}%
    \addFileDependency{#2.tex}%
    \addFileDependency{#2.aux}%
}
```

Then with `\myexternaldocument[ext-1]{Manuscript}`, `\ref{ext-1Fig1}` should work, if you have a `\label{Fig1}` in `Manuscript.tex`.