# Having latexmk recompile on file creation

Tags: latexmk

I want to have a main document which inputs files whenever they are present, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Before.
\IfFileExists{bli.tex}{\input{bli.tex}}{\typeout{No file bli.tex.}}
After.
\end{document}
```

and compile it with latexmk. If `bli.tex` exists, everything works as expected, changing `bli.tex` forces recompilation, all is well.

My issue is when I first run latexmk with no file `bli.tex` present, and then create `bli.tex`: a subsequent call to latexmk does nothing. I believe I can understand why this would be the case, as the use of `bli.tex` is not recorded when it is absent (even though there is an error message about a missing input file).

How can I set things up so that latexmk sees such file creations as triggers for recompilation?

I found the question [latexmk with external references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/latexmk-with-external-references) about a similar issue, with an answer with suggestions, but none of them seems to help me.

Comment: not directly releated but you could use `\InputIfFileExists` which has some mild optimisations over `\IfFileExists  ... \input` you could make the missing file an error then latexmk would always run unless it was there.

Comment: you can use `-g` to force it to re-run, but I'm not sure you would count that as an answer

Comment: Sure `\InputIfFileExists` is an alternative, but it has the same behavior as far as latexmk is concerned (i.e., no recompilation when I would want it).

Comment: I don't want the missing file to be an error (both situations are normal in my use case), and indeed `-g` is not optimal since figuring out when to use it would amount to reinventing part of latexmk to begin with :-) I guess I could always run `latexmk -g` whatever happens, but it does feel sub-optimal

Comment: This is actually a bug in latexmk, which I'll fix in the next release.  (Note: If you use latexmk in preview-continuous mode, i.e., with the -pvc option, the problem doesn't occur.)

Comment: I just saw that the fix appeared in version 4.72b. Thanks a lot!