# ltexmkrc for custom dep warning

Tags: overleaf, latexmk

I am following the advice in [Does hyperref work between two files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files) since that is also quoted on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf).

I have copied the code, as stated, into two files `file1.tex` and `file2.tex`. I run `latexmk file1`

However, the output contains the following:

```
Latexmk: Possible bug:
  In linking rules, I already set from_rules_main{file1.aux}
  to 'cusdep tex aux file1'
  But now I also have a different rule 'pdflatex' that also made the file.
Latexmk: Possible bug:
  In linking rules, I already set from_rules_main{file1.aux}
  to 'cusdep tex aux file1'
  But now I also have a different rule 'pdflatex' that also made the file.
Latexmk: Possible bug:
  In linking rules, I already set from_rules_main{file1.aux}
  to 'cusdep tex aux file1'
  But now I also have a different rule 'pdflatex' that also made the file.
Latexmk: All targets (file1.pdf) are up-to-date
```

The corresponding overleaf project does not have any warnings or errors in the output.

1. What is the source of the warning?
2. Why does the warning pup up 3 times?
3. Do I need to care, or should I ignore it?
4. Why does my local version spit out this error, where overleaf dont?

As context info, I have `Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020. Version 4.70b`