# Cross-ref with xr package and incremental numbering

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, appendix, xr

I have `article1.tex` and `summary.tex`. Files must be compiled separately because I need to submit two separate pdfs.

I am following [this guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf) to cross-ref equations, figures, and sections from `article1` in `summary`. However, in `summary` I further define equations and figures, and their numbering starts from 1 again.

I need either a) that numbering does not start from 1 again (preferred solution), b) equations and figures have a prefix when I reference them, like "Figure S1" instead of "Figure 1" if the figure is in the summary (something like what can be done with `\appendix` and renaming sections).

MWE is the [Overleaf example](https://www.overleaf.com/project/652aca56c962600670359633).
Just add

```
This is a new Equation
\begin{equation}
x + y    
\end{equation}
That should start from number 2 but starts from 1.
```

in `summary.tex`.

Or, full exampe here as well.

`summary.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{Using the xr package on Overleaf}

%----Helper code for dealing with external references----
% (by cyberSingularity at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69832/226)

\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
\typeout{(#1)}% latexmk will find this if $recorder=0
% however, in that case, it will ignore #1 if it is a .aux or 
% .pdf file etc and it exists! If it doesn't exist, it will appear 
% in the list of dependents regardless)
%
% Write the following if you want it to appear in \listfiles 
% --- although not really necessary and latexmk doesn't use this
%
\@addtofilelist{#1}
%
% latexmk will find this message if #1 doesn't exist (yet)
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}
%------------End of helper code--------------

% put all the external documents here!
\myexternaldocument{article1}

\begin{document}

In the file \texttt{article1.tex}, the introduction is section \ref{introduction}.  In that file, there are two subsections: \ref{mathrefs} and \ref{powers}. In subsection \ref{powers}, equation \ref{eq:1} demonstrates a power series.

This is a new Equation
\begin{equation}
x + y    
\end{equation}
That should start from number 2 but starts from 1.

\end{document}
```

`article1.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{This is \texttt{article1.tex}}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\label{introduction}

This is a standalone \LaTeX{} document with
references we want to use in \texttt{summary.tex}.

\subsection{Math references}
\label{mathrefs}
As mentioned in section \ref{introduction}, 
different elements can be referenced within
a document.

\subsection{Powers series}
\label{powers}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:1} is a typical power series.
\end{document}
```

Comment: well both is possible, but you didn't provide any code or small example that could be used to show you how.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added a link to the Overleaf example.

Comment: Sorry but I have neither the time nor the will to debug some problem from external references. Show a small but complete example *here*.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The example requires multiple files. 
I have copy-pasted the MWE here but tbh it will take you longer this way. The other is just an Overleaf example.

Comment: you can in summary.tex load the refcount package and then do at the begin `\setcounter{equation}{\getrefnumber{eq:1}}` (with the label of the last equation in your main file.).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Works like a charm, thanks! If you write it as answer I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Ulrike's comment, here are a couple of ways I found to do what I needed.
Whichever you pick, it goes after `\maketitle`.

**SOLUTION 1**

This will not reset numbering. You need to manually insert the label of the last equations/table/... from `main.tex`.

```
\setcounter{equation}{\getrefnumber{eq:last_main_eq}}
\setcounter{figure}{\getrefnumber{fig:last_main_fig}} 
% and so on
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Very generic, this will rename your figures/equations/... using the section name. If the section name has been changed by `\appendix`, they will be like "Figure A.1".

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
% and whatever else you need
```

**SOLUTION 3**

Similar to the previous, it can be customized more.

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}} % Figure A.1, A.2, B.1, ...
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}} 
% and again, whatever else you'd need
```